# Unsupported Media Type - HTTP Status 415

Tags: java, android, rest, netbeans, http-status-code-415

I have a problem with my web service.
`GET` requests are executed well and correct but the post request is getting the HTTP Status 415.

The project I am working on is a JAX-RS RESTful API that will need to communicate with an Android mobile application. I can receive the information from the `GET` statement.

This is the code of my `LoginFormat` object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class LoginFormat {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Here you can see the `POST` sample of my `CoCreationService` class:

```
@Path("/User")
public class CoCreationService {
    @POST
    @Path("/testLogin") 
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response parseTerm(LoginFormat login) {  

        return Response.status(200).entity(login.getUsername() + login.getPassword()).build();  
    }
}
```

I tried so much that I am confused from it.

I was testing the web service wit curl:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username": "testuser", "password": "test"}' http://localhost:8080/CoCreationService/api/User/testLogin
```

Is there some setting that needs to be said or did I make a crucial mistake?

PS: I am working with NetBeans.

Edit: A POST with text/plain works!

```
@POST
@Path("/testPost")
@Consumes("text/plain")
public Response postClichedMessage(String message) {       
    return Response.status(200).entity(message).build();
}
```

Comment: `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
   <version>${jersey.version}</version>
  </dependency>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. The only thing you need to do is to include proper library in your classpath which knows how to unmarshall json string. If using Maven you can simply add another dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

As long as you are using Netbeans you can see in the AS log something like this:

```
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class LoginFormat, and 
Java type class LoginFormat, and MIME media type application/json 
was not found.

The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
```

Comment: I think that i did that correctly but I still get the error. The curl request, is that right?

Comment: I tried the curl request and it is correct. Are you sure the necessary library is in your classpath? Maybe cleaning and building the project again would help.